What is the quiescent current in a current limiting voltage regulator circuit?

Is the quiescent current simply the current drawn by Q1 and Rin when no load is connected to the output? How would this differ from the supply current?

user998479 - Hi, Where did that image originally come from? In order to comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to that material. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) then please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL). If the original source was a printed book or other offline material, then [edit] the question & add a normal citation e.g. title, author(s), page, edition etc. (see the linked rule for details). TY

You can answer the question yourself if you remove RL from the schematic. Without the load current through sensing resistor Rsc will not be sufficient to activate Q2, so you can remove Q2 as well. Now, the base current of Q1 will be just enough for the voltage on divider to be equal to the voltage on zener. This means you can remove OpAmp for simplicity (keeping in mind that it supplies base current and draws some more for its own operation).
Going further, the common emitter configuration of the Q1 means that the emitter current will be a sum of the base and collector currents. This means you can also eliminate Q1, at witch point Rsc and Rf become irrelevant.
What you end up with is something like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In the end, quiescent current will be a sum of: zener current I1, divider current I2 and a very small OpAmp supply current.
